# Is there a closed-form solution for this problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a full column rank matrix. Then there exists a left inverse $A^+$ of $A$. Let $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector. Is there a closed-form solution for the following problem?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min\limits_{A^+} \ & \|{A^+}^Tw\|_1\\
\text{s.t.} \ & A^+A= I
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I don't know about a closed form, but this should be efficiently computable by linear programming -- would that help? You could also use LP duality to get analytic lower bounds on this quantity.

Comment: I'm well aware that this can be efficiently solved. I'm interested in a closed-form because in the problem I'm working on, $w$ would be a decision variable along with $A^+$

Comment: For what it's worth, it would be rather shocking if a closed-form solution exists. 1-norm minimization is one of the standard examples of how linear programming is useful. We can do 2-norm minimization in closed form, but 1-norm and infinity-norm minimization seem to require something slightly more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ is one left inverse of $A$, then $B+X$ is a left inverse of $A$ (where $X$ is $n \times m$) iff
$X A = 0$, i.e. the restriction of $X$ to $\text{Ran}(A)$ is $0$.
Of course if $A$ is surjective, there is no choice: $X$ must be $0$, so let's suppose it is not.  We may also assume $w \ne 0$.

We can choose $X$ so that $X^T w$ is any member of $\text{Ran}(A)^\perp = \text{Ker}(A^\top)$.
So the question is reduced to: find $v \in \text{Ker}(A^\top)$ to  minimize
$\|B^\top w + v\|_1$.